# How to adjust height of a HTML element to cover all free spaces of it's parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

Suppose we have a `DIV` element like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <!-- The childs will come here -->
    <div id='footer'>This is footer</div>
</div>
```

and this function that create HTML elements dynamically and inserts them into the `div#parent`

```
function addChild(name)
{
    $("<div></div>").text(name).prependTo( $("div#parent") );
}
```

CSS:

```
div#parent
{
    height:400px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
div#footer
{
    /* height: ??? */
    background-color:red;
}
```

Now I want, the element `div#footer` covers whole available/remaining height of the element `div#parent`, How I can do this by CSS or Javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using CSS. The solution here is using `display:table` and `display:table-row`

```
div#parent
{
    display:table;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}

div{
    display:table-row;
    height:20px;
}

div#footer
{
    /* height: ??? */
    background-color:red;
    height:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aawbE/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the footer to always be at the bottom of the page, then I would suggest checking out http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.  They have a great concept for making sure that the footer will either be at the end of the content, or touch the bottom of the page.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bxm53/1/)

---

If you want the footer to cover the entire bottom portion of the screen (beginning where the content ends and ending at the bottom of the screen) then you do need to know the total height being used by all of the elements inside of the "container" element as well as the height of the "container" element.

An easy way to do this is to put all child elements into a different div (the height of which you can easily track.

```
//find the difference in height between the 
//"parent" div (minimum of 100% of page height) and 
//the "main" div (the total height of its child elements)
height = document.getElementById('parent').offsetHeight -
    document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;

//Set the top margin of footer to minus the height 
//(make footer go up 'height' number of pixels
document.getElementById('footer').style.marginTop = -height+'px';

//Set the height of the footer to 'height'
document.getElementById('footer').style.height = height+'px';
```

It's important to note that these calculations are based off of the cssStickyFooter code.  This makes sure that the bottom of the footer remains at the bottom of the screen (unless it passes the bottom of the screen).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bxm53/4/)

For this example I added a green border around the 'main' div so that you can see where it ends.  I also make sure to change the footer whenever the page is re-sized in case the child elements move around (re-size the page to see this happen).  I also added a `min-height` to the footer so there will still be a footer even if `#main.height >= #parent.height`.

I hope this helps.